# Excel becomes very slow after running macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I designed a macro which will search the "source workbook" based on a primary number in the target workbook and after finding that match it will copy whole rows associated with it(normally 5 rows will be copied for a primary number ) and if there is no match it will color that row in yellow color
When I run the macro the excel sheet becomes very slow, difficult to operate with that excel sheet.
This is my code:

```
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For i = 4 To 2000
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
GoTo line

End If


Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Select
Selection.Copy
st = Cells(i, 3).Value
Windows(source).Activate



On Error GoTo error_handler

Cells.Find(What:=st, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=6

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
 Windows(target).Activate
 Range(Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 13)).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Windows(source).Activate
 Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).Select
 var1 = ActiveCell.Row
var2 = var1
  For j = 1 To 50
     If IsEmpty(Cells(var2, 3)) Then
 var2 = var2 + 1
 Else
 Exit For
 End If
   Next j
  var2 = var2 - 1
  If var2 < var1 Then
  GoTo xy
   End If

  Rows(var1 & ":" & var2).Select



  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.Copy
  Windows(target).Activate
  Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
  xy:
  line:


   error_handler:
    Windows(target).Activate


Resume label
label:
Windows(target).Activate
  Next i
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Please provide me the solution for this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: no problem ;) It's still not readable though.

Comment: :) i am running the for loop for 2000 times by assigning var3=4 ,var4=2004 .hope u got my problem ?

Comment: I didn't get it. If I did I wouldn't ask.

Comment: ok . my code will search the "source workbook" based on a primary number in the target workbook and after finding that match it will copy whole  rows associated with it(normally 5 rows will be copied for a primary number ) and if there is no match it will color that row in yellow color.

Comment: don't explain it, edit your question to make your code readable.

Comment: i don't even know where to start...  `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).Row` is same as writting activecell.row     ;   `Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value` is same as writting `Cells(i, 3).Value` ; and you use way too many `.select` and `.activate` : unnecessary, and will slow code. Instead pls set a variable to each workbook, and instead of offset i'd use a Long variable to increment ; is the smallscroll necessary ? ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2900158/patrick-lepelletier   Thanks. I have updated the macro and ran the macro.It speeded up a little but the size of excle increased and the same problem is there.one error message is displaying "there are less resources , free some resource and proceed"

Comment: you changed it to `Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value` ... It was sarcasm of patrick. That is incorrect syntax. what you say there is basically `Range("A1:A1:).` In a case like this you just say `Range(Cells(i,3)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3300784/goosebumbs    okay... but these things are not adding much of what i needed.After running this macro it is becoming very slow and size of excel is increased.My observation says that some objects created are not getting deleted.suggest me some solution

Answer (score 1):

I tried clearing the conditional formatting in the sheet and the macro runs faster.
Thank you all for attending the problem

Comment: This is not an answer ! Aadd a comment or edit your question !

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to speed up Excel when I do cells/range manipulation. Put first three lines at the beginning of your SUB and last three lines at the end of your sub & check the speed difference:

```
Sub SpeedUp()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Even nicer if you use a class module and exploit RAII semantics to unwind your changes when the class module instance goes out of scope.

Comment: I added  application.screenupdation and application.calculation into my code but that didn't help me much.The problem is still there , I guess some memory full issues may be there but don't know how to reslove .kindly help